# AngularJS Dynamic Template with indexed scope variable arrays

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, dynamicform

I'm using AngularJS and trying to create a form where I can dynamically add new inputs, similar to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V4BqE/ (Main HTML below, working code in fiddle).

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div add-input>
    <button>add input</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to use a HTML template for my form since the input I'm adding is ~300 lines long.  My issue is I cannot figure out how to index the scope variable containing the data when used in a template.  I've tried to make my own modified version of the above code  on plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/4zeaFoDeX0sGTuBMCQP2?p=info .  However, when I click the button no form elements appear.

Online (plnkr) I get a 404 not found for my template.html, but I think that is just a plnkr limitation.  On my machine with a Python HttpServer I get an `Error: [$parse:syntax]` for the `$templateRequest` and a `TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` when using the `$http.get` method.

Any advice for getting the indexed scope variable array to work with an external html file?

Thanks, JR

Edit: Update plnkr link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You can do it without directive & external template

what you are trying to do does not require a directive (it actually much simple with the basic angularjs tools)

### http://plnkr.co/edit/LVzGN8D2WSL2nR1W7vJB?p=preview

**html**

```
<body>

  <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="addPhoneInput()">add input</button>

    <form>
      <div ng-repeat="item in telephoneNumbers">
        <hr>
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.phone">
      </div>
    </form>
    
    
    <hr>
    
    <div class="well">
      <h4>Phone Numbers,</h4>
      <p ng-repeat="item in telephoneNumbers">{{item.phone}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  // Define $scope.telephone as an array
  $scope.telephoneNumbers = [];

  $scope.addPhoneInput = function() {
    $scope.telephoneNumbers.push({});
  };

  // This is just so you can see the array values changing and working! Check your console as you're typing in the inputs :)
  $scope.$watch('telephoneNumbers', function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }, true);
}]);
```

---

## If you insist using a directive,

### http://plnkr.co/edit/BGLqqTez2k9lUO0HZ5g1?p=preview

**phone-number.template.html**

```
<div>
  <hr>
  <input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" >
</div>
```

**html**

```
<body>

  <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="addPhoneInput()">add input</button>

    <form>
      <phone-number ng-repeat="item in telephoneNumbers" ng-model="item.phone"></phone-number>
    </form>
    
    
    <hr>
    
    <div class="well">
      <h4>Phone Numbers,</h4>
      <p ng-repeat="item in telephoneNumbers">{{item.phone}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  // Define $scope.telephone as an array
  $scope.telephoneNumbers = [];

  $scope.addPhoneInput = function() {
    $scope.telephoneNumbers.push({});
  };

  // This is just so you can see the array values changing and working! Check your console as you're typing in the inputs :)
  $scope.$watch('telephoneNumbers', function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }, true);
}]);

app.directive('phoneNumber', function(){
  return {
    replace:true,
     scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
    },
    templateUrl: "phone-number.template.html"
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I will try these when I get back to my programming computer this evening.

Comment: This is fantastic, does what I want.  I slightly modified your directive plnkr to include having multiple fields in the template. (http://plnkr.co/edit/9w0SXVJFABj9NgxVCQJ1?p=preview)  I'm using a directive because I want the reusability and the separation of the HTML template from the main index.html, any reasons to avoid using one?